# Add manually a custom citation to a reference database created by Mendeley

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to add manually a custom citation in LaTex to an existent reference database created by Mendeley without disturbing this tool; i.e., when synchronizing the library of Mendeley, the added citation doesn't get deleted because it doesn't figure out in Mendeley library?

Comment: You can use a second bib file to add own bib entrys and you can call this file together with the menderley file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE shows what you can do.  I used package `filecontents` to include in the MWE two bib files. Let's say the first is your menderley file, the second the new one.  Then you can use both for your literature list with the call `\bibliography{bibfile1,bibfile2}`. See the MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}            % loading package filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname1.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname2.bib}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
The funny book of Adams~\cite{adams}, the \LaTeX{} companion~\cite{companion}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\bibliography{\jobname1,\jobname2}       % uses \jobname1.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```